# Add right Yaxis in achartengine?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

[image]

I have task is chart in picture.
My problem is how to add Y Axis in right same PDF in picture.
please tell me how to do that.
Thank for watching!

Answer (score 0):

Your second line chart will have to use a different scale and the Y axis align for the second scale must be on the right. Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java) example for a working piece of code. The example builds a chart like the one below.

[image]